# Trying to override the default taxonomy behavior, from a module

Tags: taxonomy-terms

Tried to catch the routes used for taxonomy display, didn't work, which leads me to believe that I'm not taking the right approach.

```
  $items['taxonomy/term/%'] = array(
  'title' => 'Activities',
  'page callback' => 'activities_route',
  'page arguments' => array(1),
  'access arguments' => array('access content'),
```

I'm using aliases which is why i'm trying to catch the system path.

My ultimate goal is to assemble & display three views into one page, based on the vocabulary of term that is passed in. Some views are shared, while others are separate and only need to be returned for a specific vocabulary.

I'm a PHP dev, but still learning about the Drupal stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't implement [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) to override menu items of other modules. Implement [hook_menu_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7) for that.

Comment: Makes sense! I'll try it now.

Comment: It finally works! I was not getting any results with `hook_menu_alter()` and then I was reviewing the API doc and noticed the problem, my implementation was missing the parameter! `hook_menu_alter(&$items)` works as expected!